# how configure maven plugin repository

Tags: maven, plugins, repository

I'm developing new Java project depending on third party library using maven 3.8.4 as build tool. I would add that library to my local maven repository with install:install-file option. When I execute the command, I get the error

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.890 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-06T13:42:06+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\P******\.m2\repository), maven-plugins-central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/), maven-plugins-snapshots (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Here below the plugin repositories configuration in my local settings.xml :

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-plugins-central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
<pluginRepositories>
```

and the repositories configuration :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
<repositories>
```

When I check the content at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/, the pom file - maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom - exists.

I tried other URLs but none works. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: First why are you configuring the repository and not using the default defined by maven itself? Second what do you mean by: `I would add that library to my local maven ` self created library?

Comment: I tried removing the repositories configurations and the trouble persists. The project must used a library provided by IBM only available from their site.

Comment: Than you should use a repository manager instead of adding several repositories to your settings.xml file...